# How to shorten this if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an `if statement` like this:

`if(this.exercisesDoneArray[ind][i].done && this.exercisesDoneArray[ind][1].done`
`&& this.exercisesDoneArray[ind][i].exercise === this.slides.clickedSlide.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.id`
`|| this.exercisesDoneArray[ind][1].exercise === this.slides.clickedSlide.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.id){`

But I want wondering how can I shorten this..

Comment: Plese feel free to introduce some local temporary booleans to spread this out over several lines:)   Not only would the 'shape' of the code then fit the pages, it would be much easier to debug.

Comment: @NinaScholz yesh - I noticed that.  Bet you're right and it's a typo:)

Comment: Reduce the variable names? for example: `exercisesDoneArray` to `eDA`. This was tongue in cheek, but J-Titus answer is a good one.

Comment: This kind of question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using some variables?

```
var ex1 = this.exercisesDoneArray[ind][i],
    ex2 = this.exercisesDoneArray[ind][1],
    nextSlide = this.slides.clickedSlide.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.id;

if(ex1.done && ex2.done && ex1.exercise === nextSlide || ex2.exercise === nextSlide){
```

Comment: Is this also possible to do?    `if((ex1.done || ex2.done) && (ex1.exercise == nextSlide || ex2.exercise == nextSlide) || (ex1.exercise == afterNextSlide || ex2.exercise == afterNextSlide)){`

Comment: Sure, I guess; make sure `afterNextSlide` is defined. It just depends on what you're trying to accomplish with the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use few variables and then put outside the global if another if where you check if your main excercise has been done, because it has always to be done so no need to check always inside the other if with an and

```
var currentExcercise = this.exercisesDoneArray[ind][i];
var baseExcercise = this.exercisesDoneArray[ind][1];
var slideId = this.slides.clickedSlide.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.id;

if (!baseExcercise.done) {
    return false;
}
if(currentExcercise.done && currentExcercise.exercise === slideId  || baseExcercise .exercise === slideId ){
```